# Include template if a post is a single product

Tags: custom-post-types, templates

I am trying to use `include` to display my plugin template if a post is a single product

```
define( 'WCT_DIR', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );

add_filter( 'template_include', 'wdm_load_template', 99);

function wdm_load_template($template)
{
     $template_slug = basename(rtrim( $template, '.php' ));

     if( ($template_slug === 'single-product' || $template_slug === 'woocommerce') && is_product() ) 
        {
            $template = WCS_DIR . 'includes/wcs-templates.php';

        }

           return $template;
}
```

It's returning the correct path to my plugin template file but its still showing the "single-product" template instead of my plugin template.

Comment: Why can't you use the single-product template and let WordPress do the hard work for you?

Comment: You define WCT_DIR but then you try to use WCS_DIR.

Comment: Thankx for the quick response...n yaa now its working....:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Andy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/94267/andy-macaulay-brook) mentioned, you're calling `WCS_DIR`, but that doesn't exist. Updated the code to call `WCT_DIR` instead:

```
define( 'WCT_DIR', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
add_filter( 'template_include', 'wdm_load_template', 99 );

function wdm_load_template( $template ) {
    $template_slug = basename( rtrim( $template, '.php' ) );
    if ( ($template_slug === 'single-product' || $template_slug === 'woocommerce') && is_product() ) {
        $template = WCT_DIR . 'includes/wcs-templates.php';
    }
    return $template;
}
```

Comment: thankx for quick response my dat issue was resolved but now i am stuck at another..:D

Comment: i want to load a perticular template depending on the meta value stored but i am not able to achieve it

Comment: What is the meta value you are referring to? And where is this being stored exactly? Please show examples.

Comment: here is the link for my question and all the details

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/237161/how-to-include-template-according-to-meta-post-value

Comment: Great, good idea for making another question since this one is technically solved. I'll take a look at it there.