# How to include template according to meta post value

Tags: templates, post-meta, include

I'm trying to include a particular template according to the meta value stored 
for example:

> If the post meta value is `value1`, I want to include different template and if it's `value2`, I want to include different template and so on.

Here is my full code:

```
function wdm_add_meta_box() {

    add_meta_box(
            'metabox_custom', 'Plugin Options', 'wdm_meta_box_callback', 'product','normal','high');
```

}

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'wdm_add_meta_box' );

function wdm_meta_box_callback( $product ) {

```
    // Add an nonce field so we can check for it later.
    wp_nonce_field( 'wdm_meta_box', 'wdm_meta_box_nonce' );

    /*
     * Use get_post_meta() to retrieve an existing value
     * from the database and use the value for the form.
     */
    $value = get_post_meta( $product->ID, 'my_key', true );//my_key is a meta_key. Change it to whatever you want
    ?>
    <label for="wdm_new_field"><?php _e( "Enable Design Panel:", 'choose_value' ); ?></label>
    <br />  
    <input type="radio" name="tailor_select" value="value1" <?php checked( $value, 'value1' ); ?> >Value1<br>
    <input type="radio" name="tailor_select" value="value2" <?php checked( $value, 'value2' ); ?> >Value2<br>
    <input type="radio" name="tailor_select" value="value3" <?php checked( $value, 'value3' ); ?> >Value3<br>
    <input type="radio" name="tailor_select" value="value4" <?php checked( $value, 'value4' ); ?> >Value4<br>
    <input type="radio" name="tailor_select" value="value5" <?php checked( $value,'value5'); ?> >Value5<br>
    <input type="radio" name="tailor_select" value="value6" <?php checked( $value,'value6'); ?> >Value6<br>

    <?php
```

}

function wdm_save_meta_box_data( $product_id ) {

```
    /*
     * We need to verify this came from our screen and with proper authorization,
     * because the save_post action can be triggered at other times.
     */

    // Check if our nonce is set.
    if ( !isset( $_POST['wdm_meta_box_nonce'] ) ) {
            return;
    }

    // Verify that the nonce is valid.
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['wdm_meta_box_nonce'], 'wdm_meta_box' ) ) {
            return;
    }

    // If this is an autosave, our form has not been submitted, so we don't want to do anything.
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
            return;
    }

    // Check the user's permissions.
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $product_id ) ) {
            return;
    }


    // Sanitize user input.
    $new_meta_value = ( isset( $_POST['tailor_select'] ) ? sanitize_html_class( $_POST['tailor_select'] ) : '' );

    // Update the meta field in the database.
    update_post_meta( $product_id, 'my_key', $new_meta_value );
```

}

add_action( 'save_post', 'wdm_save_meta_box_data' );

function choose_option($template){

```
$has_customization = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_key', true );
echo $has_customization;
if( $has_customization == 'value2')
{
    function wdm_load_template($template)
    {
            $template_slug = basename(rtrim( $template, '.php' ));

            if( ($template_slug === 'single-product' || $template_slug === 'woocommerce') && is_product() ) 
            {
                $template = WCM_DIR . 'includes/wcm-templates.php';
            }
            return  $template;
    }
    add_filter( 'template_include', 'wdm_load_template', 99);
}
```

}

add_action( 'wp', 'choose_option');

Comment: The code that you you provides, is it in the same location where the meta value is created as well? What sort of errors are you getting with this code?

Comment: yes its in the same location and no error is there but i am not able to get the post meta into $value... $value is not showing any value when echoed so if statement is not getting executed as the condition is not met. Let me post the code for meta creation also

Comment: sorry for such clumpsy comments but m new to dis site so was not able to find out way to paste full code together....:(

Comment: Please don't post your code here. Click the [`edit`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/237161/edit) link in your question and update it from there. Better yet, please provide me the full source code so I can test your code on my end. Also, have you enabled `WP_DEBUG` mode? This can help show why your values aren't working. To enable debug mode, [see this link](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG).

Comment: @EthanJinksO'Sullivan I hav updated the full source code dat i am using so you can test it now..thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got a solution. I was not able to get meta key ie `my_key` value then I used:

```
$post_id = get_the_ID();

$has_customization = get_post_meta($post_id, 'my_key', true);
```

Comment: Be sure to click the green checkmark next to your answer to indication this question has been resolved.